# When importing pyautogui running the code breaks the script?

Tags: python, pyautogui

When I run the code through an extension in Visual Studio Code, it runs fine. But the real problem is when I open the program without the extension it errors and closes instantly. I traced the error back to this line right here.

```
import os
import pyautogui #Line Right here
from time import sleep
```

Having the import pyautogui breaks the whole script, and I really do not know why?

[This closes out when I import pyautogui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pfs31.png)

Comment: `pyautogui` is not a built-in module in Python. You need to install it first and then import it. Could you post the error as well?

Comment: I have, as I said I pip installed it and works fine in Visual Studio Code, but when I run the code outside of Visual Studio Code it doesnt work

Comment: Try running in from `cmd`.

Comment: How would I run it using command prompt?

Comment: If you could capture the error trace and post it, that would be helpful.

Comment: It closes out faster then i can take a picture as it ends the program once it errors, is there anyway way i can see this error?

Comment: There must be something with your program. If you could upload the source of this file.

Comment: VS code is likely maintaining a virtual environment with the installed packages. You're probably having an ImportError because the packages are not installed in whatever environment you're attempting to run from. Open up `cmd` prompt then type `python C:\path\to\my_script.py` to verify the error message.

Comment: I fixed the issue, it was related to not correctly installing it using pip. I hope I will learn from my mistakes, Thanks for ur help :)